# ¿Cómo restar campos de tablas diferentes usando función de Python?

Tags: python, django

Necesito restar el número de campos en la tabla de pedido y stock en el Articulo, aquí el código:

```
class Articulo(models.Model):
    cod_exp    = models.CharField(max_length=999, primary_key=True, blank=True)
    name       = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
    descrip    = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True, null=True)
    info_bod   = models.ForeignKey('Bodega', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock       = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
    extmin      = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True, null=True)
    extmax      = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True, null=True)

class Pedido(models.Model):
    espe   = models.ForeignKey('Especialidad')
    articulo       = models.ForeignKey('Articulo')
    date_ent      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    date_ped      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True, blank=True)
    cant          = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    pendiente      = models.CharField(max_length=999,  null=True, blank=True)
    status         =  models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='pendiente')
```

Uso de un botón en la plantilla que tiene la consulta en views.py
¿Cómo sería en el código en def?

```
def update_stock(request, id_pedido, id_pedido):
        pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_pedido, id_articulo)
        stock    = Articulo.objects.get(id=id_articulo)
        cant -= stock
        stock.save()
        # articulo.stock = cant
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/solicitar/lista/")
```

Sé que esto está mal, simplemente no sé cómo plantearlo, por favor ayuda! ¡Saludos!

Comment: Tu código tiene varios errores y por la forma en la que planteas la pregunta resulta demasiado amplia. Creo que voy a señalar las fallas que encuentro y la voy a marcar para cierra por "demasiado amplia". En estos casos, te recomiendo que sigas esta guía "[mcve]" y dividas tu problema en partes mas pequeñas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código no funciona porque tiene varios errores.

Veamos tu función:

```
def update_stock(request, id_pedido, id_pedido):
    pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_pedido, id_articulo)
    stock    = Articulo.objects.get(id=id_articulo)
    cant -= stock
    stock.save()
    # articulo.stock = cant
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/solicitar/lista/")
```

1. Lo primero que tendrías que revisar es la fórmula `cant -= stock`. Veamos, si tienes en almacen 5 artículos y compras dos, te quedan 3 en el almacen, ¿cierto? entonces la fórmula sería `almacen -= cantidad`.
2. Por otro lado, la variable `stock` en tu fórmula contiene **un objeto** tipo `Articulo`, pero tu quieres *la cantidad* que hay en el campo `stock`, por lo tanto debes usar la notación *punto*, lo mismo pasa con la variable `pedido`. Esto es tu fórmula quedaría así:

   ```
   stock.stock -= pedido.cant
   ```
3. Una vez que actualizaste el objeto `stock` que es una instancia del modelo `Articulo` puedes continuar con tu función.

Con estos datos, tu función quedaría así:

```
def update_stock(request, id_pedido, id_pedido):
    pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_pedido, id_articulo)
    stock = Articulo.objects.get(id=id_articulo)
    stock.stock -= pedido.cant
    stock.save()
    # ... el resto de tu función
```

### Otras recomendaciones

1. Te recomiendo encarecidamente que leas la documentación de Django. Tiene un [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) excelente y en español. Muchas de las preguntas que hacen tienen respuesta básica en la documentación, de verdad.
2. Mejora la calidad de tus preguntas, edita correctamente el código que muestras de modo que sea comprendido no solo por ti, sino por las personas que pueden ayudarte.
3. Cuéntanos sobre los errores que encuentres. Tanto los que se muestren en el navegador, como en la consola.
4. Sigue las [recomendaciones de estilo de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/) te van a ayudar mucho.